# Summing integers from a text file in each row - java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a text file and sum up all the integers in each row.
Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to get my desired output.

ie. 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (first row)
5, 6 (second row)
2, 3, 4 (third row)
10 (last row)

In this case, my output should be like:
15
11
10
10

My code is as seen below

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner fileReader = null;
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter filename> ");
                String userInput = sc.nextLine();

                File f = new File(userInput);

                //Check if file exists
                while(!f.exists()) {
                    System.out.println(userInput + " is invalid");
                    System.out.print("Enter filename> ");
                    userInput = sc.nextLine();
                    f = new File(userInput);
                }

                System.out.println("The file exists");

                //If file exists, read input
                int sum = 0;
                fileReader = new Scanner(f);
                fileReader.useDelimiter(",|\r\n"); //\r\n refers to enter

                while(fileReader.hasNext()) { 
                    String number = sc.next();
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(number);
                    System.out.println(sum);

                    if(fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                        System.out.println(sum);
                        sum = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                fileReader.close();
            };
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is current output?

Comment: and what _is_ your output

Comment: Output is the file exist but it is stucked in an endless loop.

Comment: Why not use `String::split` to split the `sc.next` line at each space then use `Stream` API to sum the returned `Array.toList()`?

Answer (score 0):

i prefer buffered reader for reading files. so i wrote you a solution with one. this checks if each char in the line is numeric or not. if yes, it will be added to the sum

```
String line;
int sum;
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++){
            if(Character.isDigit(line.charAt(i))){
                sum+=line.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```